# Get exact Ansible command that is being executed

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is it possible to know exactly what command the following Ansible code will execute on the remote server

```
- name: Ensure apache is running
    service: name=httpd state=started
    become: true
```

I believe the user should have the appropriate sudo rights. However, I keep getting `sudo: a password is required`.

**Update #1**

In light of provided comments, here is my full Ansible command:

```
ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 sudo -u userA ansible-playbook ssl_playbook.yml -i inventories/staging --extra-vars "target=my_server_set" --private-key=/path/to/ssh.key --u userB  -vvv
```

- userB is the remote user where the SSH key specified has been configured
- userB has limited sudo rights. I cannot change this unfortunately, I'm not the server admin.
- userB is currently configured to access a bunch of servers via SSH/Key already, it seemed a prime candidate for Ansible. I'm currently able to manage all my middleware manually via SSH (Apache, Tomcat, Jenkins, etc) and wanted to automate it using Ansible.

Comment: `ansible-playbook -vvv` will show you exact command to launch module.

Comment: I had been running `-vvvv` actually, and noticed that it was running a .tmp file using `sudo -H -S -n -u root...`. I also enabled the environment variable `ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES` so that I could view these files. However, once I opened a .tmp file, I wasn't able to determine exactly what was happening.

Comment: Can you manually run `sudo` on the remote host without a password? Can you show us your `sudoers` configuration? Do other tasks fail, or just `service` tasks?

Comment: Yes, I constantly run sudo without a password. I have a limited set of commands though. For instance sudo service httpd start|restart|status. Now that you mention it, some tasks were completing, and those specifying service have issues. Secondly, I wonde if I couldn't simply issue raw commands instead? I would rather use more standard Ansible code though.

Comment: See the updates to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your first question ("Is it possible to know exactly what command the following Ansible code will execute on the remote server?") is generally "only by inspecting the source for the corresponding module".  A given module may run *multiple* commands in order to accomplish it's action.

The error message you are seeing ("`sudo: a password is required.`") does not suggest that the remote user does not have appropriate `sudo` rights.  It only suggests that the remote user is not configured for passwordless `sudo`.  Your two options are:

1. Provide a password to Ansible:

   ```
   ansible-playbook -K secretpassword ...
   ```
2. Modify the `sudoers` configuration on the remote host to allow passwordless `sudo`:

   ```
   remoteuser ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD:ALL
   ```

Sudo configuration that involve a limited set of commands probably won't work, because Ansible is running a *script* using `sudo`.  For example, if I run `ansible-playbook -vvv` against the following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ping:
      become: true
```

I will see:

```
<localhost> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/lars/.ansible/cp/8a5a4c6a60 -tt localhost '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-rebjujbhceobxvfuylirykxzgdonillt; /usr/bin/python /home/lars/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1505503292.11-47458712165303/ping.py; rm -rf "/home/lars/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1505503292.11-47458712165303/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
```

In other words, ansible is running:

```
sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '...embedded script here...'
```

The only command that `sudo` ever sees is `/bin/sh`, which means that a `sudo` configuration that limits you to only certain commands is doomed to fail.

If you're unable to fix the remote `sudo` configuration, you may want to investigate ansible's [raw](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/raw_module.html) module.

Comment: I added update #1... I had a glance at the embedded script and wasn't able to immediately decipher anything. I had assumed that it was essentially running sudo service httpd status, which may not be the case.

Comment: No, the point is that the `sudo` is *outside* the script.  So you *can't* use a `sudo` configuration that is limited to specific commands.  The only command that `sudo` sees is `/bin/sh`.

Comment: I had thought about the raw command. I'm curious how I would test Apache status with a raw command though. The start|stop of a service would be feasible I'm sure.